# Equalizer.usePreset throws Invalid argument exception

Tags: android, equalizer

I'm creating mediaPlayer with EQ, when I set the EQ bands it works fine. I have code that lists all presets, on change I want to set the preset to EQ, but I'm getting `bad parameter value`.

This is what I have in my log:

```
09-29 14:29:24.810: W/System.err(27829): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AudioEffect: bad parameter value
09-29 14:29:24.835: W/System.err(27829):    at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.checkStatus(AudioEffect.java:1259)    
09-29 14:29:24.835: W/System.err(27829):    at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.usePreset(Equalizer.java:342)
```

getNumberOfPresets() returns 12
and preset to set for this example is 2 (but it happens for all values 0-11)

If I use `setBandLevel()` before `usePreset()` it's not throwing an exception, but i'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. 
Edit: setBandLevel has nothing to do with the exception. It just pops out randomly, 80% of the tries.

Update: I noticed that this is happening on Samsung S3 devices (for now) only. Works fine on Asus TF101.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);
mEqualizer.usePreset((short)mEQPresetPos);
```

Comment: Show us the code how you are calling the Equalizer.

Comment: I updated the question with code.

Comment: I don't understand how this code sometimes works and sometimes throws exception, for same mEQPresetPos value.

Comment: What is the value of mEQPresetPos ?

Comment: Have you tried calling setEnabled as last? Seems more logical to first setup the equalizer and then activate it.

Comment: `getNumberOfPresets() = 12`
mEQPresetPos in this example is 2 (but it happens for all values 0-11). it's not > 11 for sure. again, for same value sometimes works sometimes not.

Comment: nothing changed by moving setEnabled as last, I even removed that line.

Comment: I've set breakpoint to check mEqualizer properties. As i can see, they are the same both times (when works and when it's not)

Comment: another strange thing. this is happening on Samsung Galaxy S3 i9300 (reported by now, and tested by me). on asus tf101 works fine.

Comment: A bit more code wouldn't hurt. Specifically, where/how `mEQPresetPos` gets initialized/assigned.

Comment: mEQPresetPos is set on spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener, where spinner adapter is filled with getPresetName(0 to (getNumberOfPresets() -1))
the value is not the problem, again, mEQPresetPos in this example is 2 (but it happens for all values 0-11). it's not > 11 for sure. again, for same value sometimes works sometimes not. so, if i set it as const=0, the problem will still be there (on i9300 device).

Comment: ok. how i solved the problem. i know it's not a good solution, but here it is: i have a loop (with max repeat counter = 10), it resets the mEqualizer and call usePreset until not throws an error. so far so good.

Comment: Hey @cucko did your solution work out? What exception did you catch? I'm having the same issue with various devices reported by users. :/

Comment: no solution yet. i'm still using the code from my prev comment.

Comment: I am getting the same error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation on Android 7.0 and its working fine on 6.0

Comment: provide the entire source code so we can debug :P

Answer (score 3):

**It may be due to two reasons.**

your device may be not supporting Equalizer. But as you said you get a list of Preset. It means it is supporting.

Now the problem may be that you have two instance of Equalizer. you must release Equalizer.

or try

add 
`equalizer.setEnabled(false);`

before creating another one.

Comment: does any1 got the solution?

Comment: he is right about the two instace problem of Equalizer

Comment: didnt try with the api 25 but the things working with my 5.1.1 device

Comment: I have tested equalizer on 6.0 its working fine, but getting crashed on 7.0